# how to turn 1 row in SQL into multiple rows and then sum

Tags: sql

My input data looks like this - how can I turn table 1 into table 2 where the 1st row gets split into 3 in this example? how can I then turn table 2 into table 3 where I sum 3 rows into 1

Table 1

```
Task       |Month1 |Month1 plan in % |Month2 plan in % |Month3 plan in %
-----------+-------+-----------------+-----------------+----------------
Data entry |Jun-17 |40               |40               |20
Processing |Jul-17 |30               |70
Delivery   |Aug-17 |70               |30
```

Table 2

```
Task        |Year   |Month      |% work planned
------------+-------+-----------+--------------
Data entry  |2017   |June       |40
Data entry  |2017   |July       |40
Data entry  |2017   |August     |20
Processing  |2017   |July       |30
Processing  |2017   |August     |70
Delivery    |2017   |August     |70
Delivery    |2017   |September  |30
```

Table 3

```
Task        |Year   |Month  |Total % work completed
------------+-------+-------+----------------------
Data entry  |2017   |July   |80
Processing  |2017   |July   |30
Delivery    |2017   |July   |0
Data entry  |2017   |August |100
Processing  |2017   |August |100
Delivery    |2017   |August |70
```

Comment: You should choose one question or the other.

Comment: What DBMS are you using? What version? Please add relevant tags to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what type of database you are using, so I decided to use PostgreSQL. Some specifics will vary, but the ideas should work in other database types.

Table #2 can be produced with a union.

Example:

```
select "Task", "Month1", "Month1 plan in %" from data                                                                                                                          
union                                                                                                                                                                          
select "Task", "Month1", "Month2 plan in %" from data                                                                                                                          
union                                                                                                                                                                          
select "Task", "Month1", "Month3 plan in %" from data
```

To make it easier to work with the data, alias the combined data set. Like this:

```
select "Task", "Month1", "% work planned" from (
select "Task", "Month1", "Month1 plan in %" as "% work planned" from data 
union all 
select "Task", "Month1", "Month2 plan in %" as "% work planned" from data 
union all
select "Task", "Month1", "Month3 plan in %" as "% work planned" from data
) as combined where "% work planned" is not null;
```

Notice that I added a where condition to exclude null values. This because column 3 contains null values.

Lastly you will need to substring, string replace and CAST to a date then print out the month of that date. Here is an example:

```
 select to_char(
   (
     (substring('Jul-17', '...') || 
     '-01' || 
     substring('Jul-17', '...$'))::date
   ), 
   'MONTH') AS MONTH;
```

Use a sum on table 2 to produce table 3.

Comment: Thanks user1094125 - table 2 works for me - that is great. I work in MS SQL Mgmt studio and the date manipulation using the to_char function, double colons & pipes is not familiar to me. could you please elaborate in MSSQL that would be great...

Comment: Hey texastonie, No problem. If you could kindly credit me for the answer I would be most appreciative.